# Two PHPBB questions

Tags: passwords, registration, phpbb

I was wondering if i could get some help with two questions I have:

Firstly, is is possible, assuming I have a random variable to load up two different registration screens? Ie. one with and without the captcha? or one with and without some other stuff i would like to use?

Secondly, is it possible to have a second log in box? say someone is already logged in, to display another to them which could potentially allow them to log in again or as I want to use it, show they know another persons password?

Comment: I would suggest asking two separate questions and be much more specific in the question title.

Comment: When I first saw the title I read it as "Two PHB questions" and wondered why you were asking management questions here? :)

Answer (score 1):

Chris have you tried asking the guys on the [phpBB community forums](http://www.phpbb.com/community/?sid=fde569d6a492d70273b878edfeece0f4)?

They might be able to help you as I would assume that modifying phpBB is thier bread and butter.

http://www.phpbb.com/community/?sid=fde569d6a492d70273b878edfeece0f4

Comment: I have asked but they are not great at getting back to you...

And one guy who did get back to me(via pm) was rather rude, so that put me off.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to check is the [phpBB MOD database](http://www.phpbb.com/mods/db/) on the phpBB website to see if someone else has already done it.

If you do find some that do what you want, make sure it's for the correct version.  phpBB2 mods will not work on phpBB3 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

phpBB is open source, so you can modify it to do both those things - but they are not options available out-of-the-box.